# What is a code repository sub-package imports?

Tags: python, google-style-guide

Looking at the Google Python Style Guide under 3.13 it says order of imports should be:

1. Python Future Imports
2. Python Standard imports
3. Third Party module or package import
4. Code repository sub-package imports

What exactly is `Code repository sub-package imports` ? If there is a library written by another team in the company is that Third Party or is it Code Repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Code repository sub-package imports" means a package that lives in the projects' directory.

If you have `main.py` and `utils.py`, you will do `from utils import magic_algorithm` last.

So, following that logic the entire thing might look like

```
from __future__ import braces       # future import
import re                           # python built-in import
from requests import Session        # third-party import
from utils import magic_algorithm   # code repository import
```